# How can I get the Terminal to keep a separate history per tab/window?

Tags: terminal

When I restart my Mac it quits and saves the buffers for each tab properly, since it's there again when the computer starts back up. But the command history is not buffered properly per window/tab. They're all the same buffer.

I'm assuming it's because bash uses the same `~/.bash_history` for all terminals but is there a way to <strike>avoid</strike> improve this? To make bash, or maybe Terminal, store them separately?

Comment: Please see [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/88460/is-it-possible-to-have-a-unique-bash-history-file-per-host) @ Server Fault, it explains how to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do something like this in your `.bashrc`:

```
MYTTY=`tty`
HISTFILE=$HOME/.bash_history_`basename $MYTTY`
```

This will create separate history files in your home directory such as `.bash_history_ttys002`.  When you create a new terminal window, it will use the history file corresponding to the tty name, which will usually be determined simply by the order in which you create the terminal windows.

Comment: Great, thanks! Marking this as solved. Even though it kind of depends on how OSX loads the terminals I have a feeling this is the closest we can get.

Comment: Is this also possible per-tab??

Comment: Each tab is a separate tty login, so it should work.

Comment: Terminal has explicit support for this type of behavior: when it creates a new terminal it assigns the terminal a unique ID and communicates it to the terminal session via the TERM_SESSION_ID environment variable. When it restores a terminal for Resume it also restores the same session ID so programs can use this to associate arbitrary state with restored terminals. Use this as part of the file name instead of the tty.

Comment: @ChrisPage the problem with this is that the session is different each time you launch a window/tab. So it would create separate histories and not link them across sessions.

Comment: @ReneWooller: OS X El Capitan 10.11 does this by default, and the independent histories are also merged into the global history so new terminals pick up commands from other terminals—if that's what you're referring to. See `/etc/bashrc_Apple_Terminal` for details.

Answer (score 10):

I implemented this by adding

```
export HISTFILE="$HOME/.bash_history_$TERM_SESSION_ID"
if [ ! -e $HISTFILE ]; then cp "$HOME/.bash_history" "$HISTFILE"; fi
```

to my `~/.bash_profile` file. Now when I close terminal and open it again, each tab has its separate command history restored. Also when I create new tab, default history is initialized from `.bash_history`

Also to make `Terminal` app to preserve opened tabs between quit and restart you need to make sure that option `"close windows when quitting app" (on Yosemite)` is disabled in `System Preferences -> General`.

Comment: For my homebrew installed bash 5, I had to add these commands to `.bashrc`, when they were in `.bash_profile` the shell continued to use `.bash_history` and ignored my `$HISTFILE` value.

Comment: For ZSH, I put the following into my .zshrc file: `export HISTFILE="$HOME/.zsh_history_$TERM_SESSION_ID" if [ ! -e $HISTFILE ]; then cp "$HOME/.zsh_history" "$HISTFILE"; fi`

Answer (score 0):

You can set a custom $HISTFILE for each of you Terminal instances.

Comment: Is there a way to do this automatically for each Terminal tab/window? And make sure it's using the same `$HISTFILE` when the computer starts back up?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do this, but then how would you access again?  You'd manually have to juggle files to get to the previous history files.

Comment: @EmmEff Terminal has explicit support for this type of behavior: when it creates a new terminal it assigns the terminal a unique ID and communicates it to the terminal session via the TERM_SESSION_ID environment variable. When it restores a terminal for Resume it also restores the same session ID so programs can use this to associate arbitrary state with restored terminals.